# Import Object Sequence into Blender

Tags: python, animation, blender

Does any know of a way to import an object sequence into blender as shape keys? The object sequence I have has a varying number of vertices. The only python script I found only works when the vertices are consistent through the object sequence. Otherwise the script just imports every frame as objects instead of shape keys. [http://www.blenderinmotion.com/controlling-blender-physics.php.](http://Does%20any%20know%20of%20a%20way%20to%20import%20and%20object%20sequence%20into%20blender%20as%20shape%20keys?%20The%20object%20sequence%20has%20a%20varying%20number%20of%20vertices.%20The%20only%20python%20script%20i%20found%20only%20works%20when%20the%20vertices%20are%20consistent%20through%20the%20object%20sequence.%20http://www.blenderinmotion.com/controlling-blender-physics.php.)